# MongoMapper Error "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 when storing a file in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, mongodb, mongomapper, ruby-1.9

I have a problem to Store file (from a remote API) in MongoDB, i'm with Ruby 1.9

```
class Foo
  include ::MongoMapper::Document
  key :bar, String
end
```

I get the following error : "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I tried the following things :

```
foo.bar = pdf_data.encode('UTF-8')
foo.bar = pdf_data.force_encoding('UTF-8')
foo.bar = pdf_data.ensure_encoding('UTF-8',
  :external_encoding  => :sniff,
  :invalid_characters => :transcode
) # with github.com/Manfred/Ensure-encoding
```

Well any of them work, I get an error while save call ...

I look on the net but I didn't find any clear responce (or at least solving my probleme)...
Any idea what i'm supposed to do to be able to store it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `TempFile`, make sure you put it into binary mode. An example:

```
file = Tempfile.new('tmp').tap do |file|
  file.binmode # must be in binary mode
  file.write image.to_blob
  file.rewind
end
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me, though I can't guarantee this is the cause in your case.